# NSURLSession - DownloadTask doesn't work with some URL

Tags: ios, swift

- Here the code:

  ```
  let url = NSURL(string: "http://a337.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/d5/a8/6b/mzi.msfqeogi.aac.p.m4a")
  let downloadTask = self.downloadSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url!)
  downloadTask.resume()
  ```

-> OK

- Replace the URL with: 
  http://s1mp3.r41s223.vcdn.vn/d3f549abeeef07b15efe/2937387453157939420?key=c2WuQChtsmR9yfdz9I-jnw&expires=1480695588&filename=Only%20Love%20-%20Trademark.mp3

-> it doesn't work; nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

By default starting in iOS 9 all connections must be https.  If the website for the second URL doesn't support https:// then the download would fail.

I suggest checking the error code you get back from the Download

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use url with HTTP connection, then in your info.plist file add the following
App Transport Security Setting and in that add subsection Allow Arbitrary Loads and set the value to YES.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Please add in Plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>graph.facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then using Alamofire 4.0 Swift 3.0

Using below method, you can download any thing, ex. PDF

```
 // Mark:- Download File
    func DownloadFile(strFileUrl : String, strFileName : String, success:@escaping (_ strResultURL: String) -> Void , failure:@escaping (_ responseObject:AnyObject) -> Void) {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(strFileName)")

            return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        Alamofire.download(strFileUrl, to: destination).response { response in

                if SVProgressHUD.isVisible() {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }

                if response.error == nil {
                    success("\(response.destinationURL!)")
                }
                else {
                    failure(response.error as AnyObject)
                }
            }.downloadProgress { (progress) in
                print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(progress.fractionCompleted), status: AppAlertMsg.KDownloadingPDFs)
        }
    }
```